# Auto serial number in column

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am try generate auto serial no. starting from 500 (**like ABC 500, ABC 501 and so on**) by using Array Formula in my *google sheets.*

Is there any solution ??

Comment: a1=ABC b1=500 b2=b1+1 c1=concat($a$1;b1) than use the fill handle on b2 and c1

Answer (score 1):

`=ARRAYFORMULA("ABC "&SEQUENCE(3,1,500,1))` will do the trick. Read up on the specifics of the functions in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273).

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("ABC"&ROW(A500:A1000))
```

or bind it to just valid non-empty rows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>"";;"ABC"&ROW(A500:A1000)))
```